# koa.js mongoose check collection exists on server start

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, koa

I am new to koa.js, using it with mongoose, and have the following scenario: on app start, I want to load a json file, and populate the mongo database with the content of the json if the collection doesn't already exist using mongoose.  I have created a generator function loadMusicJSONIntoDB to handle the load, and wrap that function in a co block with app.listen so it happens before the server starts.

In the snippet below, I am able to use mongoose's listConnection after hooking into mongoose.connection.on('open' ...), that part is commented out.  And I want to check for the existence of Song collection, using yield inside loadMusicJSONIntoDB.

app.js:

```
var koa = require('koa');
var co = require('co');
var Song = require('./models/song');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
// mongoose
var connection = mongoose.connect('localhost/test');
...
// Checking for collection exist like this works
// mongoose.connection.on('open', function () {
//   mongoose.connection.db.listCollections({name: 'songs'})
//     .next(function(err, collinfo) {
//         if (collinfo) {
//           console.log("songs collection exists")
//         }
//     });
// });

function *loadMusicJSONIntoDB() {
  console.log("loadMusicJSONIntoDB");
  var parsedMusicJSON = require('./music.json');
  //console.log(parsedMusicJSON);
  try {

    // QUESTION: I would like to do a yield to wait for the connection
    // to be established?

    // songs = yield mongoose.connection.db.listCollections({name: 'songs'})
    //   .next(function(err, collinfo) {
    //        if (collinfo) {
    //          console.log(collinfo);
    //          console.log("songs collection exists")
    //        }
    //    });

    // Would like to do the following only if the songs collection does not exist
    for (var key in parsedMusicJSON) {
      if (parsedMusicJSON.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + " -> " + parsedMusicJSON[key]);
        result = yield Song.findOne({name: key});
        //console.log(result);
        if (!result) { // create record
          var record = { name: key, tags: parsedMusicJSON[key]};
          console.log(record);
          yield Song.create(record);
        }

      }
    }

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);

  }

};

co(function*() {
  yield loadMusicJSONIntoDB;
  app.listen(3001, function() { console.log('listening on 3001') });
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.error('Server boot failed:', err, err.stack);
});
```

song.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;
var SongSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  tags: []
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Song", SongSchema);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I ended up doing, yield the connection inside the co block before app.listen.  but I don't fully understand how my solution is able to work, specifically this part inside app.js:
    songs = yield mongoose.connection.db.listCollections({name: 'songs'}).next()

app.js

```
function *loadMusicJSONIntoDB() {
  //console.log("loadMusicJSONIntoDB");
  var parsedMusicJSON = require('./music.json');
  //console.log(parsedMusicJSON);
  try {
    songs = yield mongoose.connection.db.listCollections({name: 'songs'}).next()
    console.log(songs);
    // if the song collection doesn't exist
    if (!songs)
    {
      for (var key in parsedMusicJSON) {
        if (parsedMusicJSON.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          console.log(key + " -> " + parsedMusicJSON[key]);

          //result = yield Song.findOne({name: key});
          //console.log(result);
          //if (!result) { // create record
          var record = { name: key, tags: parsedMusicJSON[key]};
          console.log(record);
          yield Song.create(record);
          //}

        }
      }
    }

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);

  }

};

co(function*() {
  yield mongoose.connect('localhost/test');
  yield loadMusicJSONIntoDB;
  app.listen(3001, function() { console.log('listening on 3001') });
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.error('Server boot failed:', err, err.stack);
});
```

On http://koajs.com/, we have the example in chaining together middleware of doing yield next, but in my example above, if I do the next without calling it with (). 
ie.
songs = yield mongoose.connection.db.listCollections({name: 'songs'}).next 
Then I get
[TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentDoc' of undefined]

On the other hand,
songs = yield mongoose.connection.db.listCollections({name: 'songs'}).next () works.

Here is the documentation I found on mongodb, listCollections, but I am still unsure of the next() behavior reading it. 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/listCollections/